# Macports with Xcode CLI tools only

Tags: xcode, macports

I ve installed the latest version of MacPorts and Xcode CLI tools for OS X 10.10 - I don't want download 4GB of data because I need only GCC.
Everything looks fine - I can download and compile ports, except the one thing - every time when I try to install new port I get following messages:

```
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
```

But as I said before everything works fine. Should I worry or just ignore these messages?

Comment: Some tutorials claim that *both* Xcode *and* Command Line Tools (CLT) are required. I only installed Xcode; no issue so far.

Answer (score 1):

You might be lucky and ports work :)

I think the latest I saw in the [mailing lists](https://www.macports.org/contact.php#Lists) is that most ports will work. The issue is for GUIS and there other issues.

Note that Xcode for OS X 10.10 does not supply gcc, it uses clang. However this works just as well if not better.

Comment: Ah, sorry I forgot about clang - I am new on mac, just switched from GNU/Linux :)

Comment: More specifically, see these posts https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35045 and https://trac.macports.org/ticket/29172 where people argue whether this error should be shown at all. Likely all your ports will work, and if it doesn't you can always install Xcode.