# Is it possible to use MacPorts without Xcode or Apple ID?

Tags: apple-id, xcode, macports

MacPorts requires XCode. One seems to be only able to install XCode through the App store which requires an Apple Id to install stuff. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/159612/macports-with-xcode-cli-tools-only?rq=1 See if just installing the CLI tools works or not. `xcode-select --install`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366125/xcode-select-install-failing

Comment: You can also obtain Xcode from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/, but I believe that you require an Apple ID to access that too. If you tell me what version of macOS you have, I can download and then upload the version of Xcode you need to a file sharing service.

Comment: Can you document why MacPorts requires Xcode? Brew,sh installs the command line tools and doesn’t require Xcode. The premise here doesn’t line up to my expectations without some more documentation. Maybe I’m wrong, so no downvote is needed.

Comment: Check @simba 's answer. MacPorts just warns you that xcode is not installed. Most work without xcode. I have yet to run into any issues and I only have the command line tools installed.

Comment: @Philippe Please report back to this question if you meet any issue using MacPorts with only CLT! I’m curious as well. I think CLT should suffice for majority of the ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only install Xcode CLI tool, since most of the ports work without Xcode although there's a warning during use.

[Quote from Google Summer of Code 2019 for MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/SummerOfCode#xcode)

> Phase out dependency on Xcode (done in the main repo)
>
> MacPorts currently requires a full Xcode installation, **even though a lot of ports will install just fine with the Command Line Tools package only**. Since we also have a number of ports that need Xcode to build, we cannot completely remove the Xcode dependency. Your task would be to provide a way for maintainers to easily identify ports that depend on Xcode and mark them as such, so MacPorts can warn users without Xcode installed that a port they want to install needs the full Xcode package.

references

- [Summer of Code for MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/SummerOfCodeArchive)

Comment: Interestingly, when Xcode is available, CLT (Command Line Tools) seems redundant. I guess Xcode is a strict superset of CLT.